# why is RC= exactly 63.2% full charge, and how is 5RC considered 100%?

Tags: charge, discharge

The voltage of a charging and discharging capacitor is given by the formulas:

$$U_C=U e^{-t/(RC)}$$

and

$$U_C=U \left(1-e^{-t/(RC)}\right)$$

respectively, but I don't understand why RC is equal to 63.2% of full charge.

I also don't understand how 5RC is found and why it is chosen to be considered a full charge.

Answer (score 9):

Take a look how a capacitor charges through a resistor: -

[image]

Capacitor charging follows this exponential relationship: -

[image]

Where Vs is the target "supply" voltage and, if you let t=CR you find that Vc/Vs = 0.632 or 63% for short: -

\$\dfrac{V_C}{V_S} = (1-e^{-1}) = 0.632120558
\$

When you do the math of stacking 5 lots of "63%" on top of each other you get: -

Vc = 0.99326 x Vs or, put another way, 5CR gets you to within 1% of the full charging voltage.

Try [this page](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/rc/rc_1.html) for more background info.

Comment: To the guy (@JonasWielicki) proposing an edit, I have rejected it because I was still in the process of editing it myself so, take a look now and let me know what it is that you were attempting to improve.

Comment: 5RC (within 1%) is "good enough" for some engineering tasks. For more fussy engineers, more settling time is required. For example, settling time for 12-bit analog-to-digital converters  requires about nine RC, not five.

Comment: @glen_geek I certainly do agree!

Comment: Thanks Andy, you really hit the nail on the head! and also glen_geek, makes sense that there are different standards in different tasks

Comment: @RyanAbbas thanks on EE is best done by formally accepting the best answer but thank you anyway.